# NFTables Egress Hook?

Tags: nftables, netfilter

I'm looking to apply firewall rules on egress to control DHCP output from a Docker container. I don't want the DHCP container to share the host's network stack as adding `CAP_NET_ADMIN` effectively gives the container control of the network stack.

I notice [here](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Netfilter_hooks#Priority_within_hook) that an egress hook was added to netfilter in kernel 5.7 (`uname -r` says I have 5.10).

According to information in [this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=8537f78647c072bdb1a5dbe32e1c7e5b13ff1258) commit, I have added the following table:

```
table netdev filterfinal_lan {
    chain egress {
        type filter hook egress device enp1s0 priority 0; policy accept;
    }
}
```

However when I attempt to apply the config it tells me it's not recognised:

```
/etc/nftables.conf:107:20-25: Error: unknown chain hook
                type filter hook egress device enp1s0 priority 0; policy accept;
                                 ^^^^^^
```

I'm unsure which version of nftables supports the egress hook, but my `nft --version` is `nftables v0.9.8 (E.D.S.)`. Information on the egress hook seems quite elusive.

What is required to enable the use of this hook?

Comment: Does `ingress` rule as a test work? It might be missing kernel module. Add output of `lsmod | sort` to your post.

Comment: `lsmod | sort` gives a very long output, but I know that the `ingress` rule works as I have it in the config too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually *nftables*'s egress hook was added in kernel 5.16, and improved support (`fwd`) in 5.17.

There were several attempts earlier, and one of them was NACK-ed at the same time it was initially committed, making it appear in Kernel Newbies for version 5.7, and apparently even *nftables*' wiki has it wrong by linking to Kernelnewbies for Linux 5.7 instead of Linux 5.16.

Here is a relevant mailing list link from March 2020 (around kernel 5.7):

> [Subject:    Re: [PATCH 00/29] Netfilter updates for net-next](https://marc.info/?l=netfilter-devel&m=158451911400849&w=2)
> From:       David Miller <davem () davemloft ! net>
>
> From: Alexei Starovoitov <alexei.starovoitov@gmail.com>
> Date: Tue, 17 Mar 2020 20:55:46 -1000
>
> > On Tue, Mar 17, 2020 at 2:42 PM Pablo Neira Ayuso pablo@netfilter.org wrote:
> >
> > > 15. Add new egress hook, from Lukas Wunner.
> >
> > NACKed-by: Alexei Starovoitov ast@kernel.org
>
> Sorry I just saw this after pushing this pull request back out.
>
> Please someone deal with this via a revert or similar.

It was subsequently reverted in this commit: [netfilter: revert introduction of egress hook](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/netdev/net-next.git/commit/?id=357b6cc5834eabc1be7c28a9faae7da061df097d). This revert might not have been posted in all relevant mailing lists, adding a bit to the confusion.

---

Fast forward almost two years. Issues and concerns (among them about interactions with tc/qdisc) having been addressed, *egress* was added again in kernel 5.16 (9 Jan 2022). [Kernelnewbies for Linux 5.16](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.16#Networking) has this entry:

> Netfilter
>
> - Support classifying packets with netfilter on egress [commit](https://git.kernel.org/linus/7463acfbe52ae8b7e0ea6890c1886b3f8ba8bddd), [commit](https://git.kernel.org/linus/17d20784223d52bf1671f984c9e8d5d9b8ea171b), [commit](https://git.kernel.org/linus/42df6e1d221dddc0f2acf2be37e68d553ad65f96), [commit](https://git.kernel.org/linus/0d7308c0ff5fa7c77164ab8491a91e0589da66e3)

On Linux Kernel Driver Database:

> [CONFIG_NETFILTER_EGRESS](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NETFILTER_EGRESS.html): Netfilter egress support
>
> [...]
>
> - found in Linux kernels: 5.16–5.19, 5.19+HEAD

---

Likewise, *nftables* userland support for *egress* was officially added only after kernel support was committed in nf-next (so a bit before 5.16 was out) and was made available in the [nftables 1.0.1 release](https://lwn.net/Articles/876497/):

> This release contains new features available up to the Linux kernel
> 5.16-rc1 release:
>
> [...]
>
> - egress hook support (available since 5.16-rc1).

OP's ruleset is accepted on a kernel with relevant kernel option `CONFIG_NETFILTER_EGRESS` which has to be version >= 5.16 along *nftables* >= 1.0.1.

Comment: Thanks. Is upgrading one's kernel and nftables version risky if the system is used in a production (home router) environment? I'm concerned aswell about automatic updates and leaving behind more binaries (from having to compile) for an attacker to use should they gain access to the system.

Comment: Some distributions sometimes provide packaged newer versions in alternate channels (eg Debian 11 provides newer kernels using bullseye-backports but currently doesn't provide newer nftables). I'd worry first about a nonfunctional result. You can compile elsewhere than on the router and install the result as package, but if it's about cross-compiling ok that's not the easiest (though using qemu to compile in an LXC container in an other arch is even a (slow) possibility). Anyway you never hinted what's the environment.